# How to bind a list of objects in ASP.NET Core MVC when the posted list is smaller than original?

Tags: view, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

Using "disabled" attribute on inputs on form does not post them, which is expected and wanted. However, if you prepare a form of 3 objects in a list, disable the first and third, and submit, the 2nd object appears in post header, but does not bind to the list correctly, because it has an index [1] instead of [0].

I understand how model binding works and why it does not bind the posted object that I want, but I don't know how else to describe the problem to get specific results that would lead me to my solution. Anything I search for leads to basic post and binding examples.

List inside the model I'm using:

```
public IList<_Result> Results { get; set; }
```

Class _Result has one of the properties:

```
public string Value { get; set; }
```

I fill up the list and use it in view like so:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Results.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    <td>
        <input asp-for="Results[i].Value" disabled />
    </td>
    ...
}
```

I have checkboxes on form, which remove (with javascript) the "disabled" attribute from the inputs and thus allow them to be posted.

When I fill up the said list with 3 _Result objects, they are shown on form and all have the "disabled" attribute. If I remove the "disabled" attribute from the first two objects and click on submit button, I receive the Results list with first 2 _Result objects, which is as expected.

However, if I remove the "disabled" attribute only from the second _Result object (the first _Result object still has "disabled" attribute), the Results list comes back empty in my Controller method.
In my Form Data Header, I see this: "Results[1].Value: Value that I want posted", which means that post occurs, but list does not bind the object due to the index.

Any idea on how I can achieve that proper binding? Also, the reason I'm using "disabled" attribute is because I'm showing many results on a single page and want to only post those that are selected.

Answer (score 1):

For getting selected items, you could try checkbox with View Model instead of using jquery to control the disable property.

1. Change ViewModel

   ```
   public class ModelBindVM
   {
       public IList<_ResultVM> Results { get; set; }
   }
   public class _ResultVM
   {
       public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
       public string Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Controller

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult ModelBindTest()
   {
       ModelBindVM model = new ModelBindVM
       {
           Results = new List<_ResultVM>() {
               new _ResultVM{ Value = "T1" },
               new _ResultVM{ Value = "T2" },
               new _ResultVM{ Value = "T3" }
           }
       };
       return View(model);
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult ModelBindTest(ModelBindVM modelBind)
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```
3. View

   ```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <form asp-action="ModelBindTest">
               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Results.Count; i++)
               {
                   <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Results[i].IsSelected" />
                   <label asp-for="@Model.Results[i].IsSelected">@Model.Results[i].Value</label>
                   <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Results[i].Value" />
               }
               <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Doing it this way, it posts "IsSelected" property too. If I had 1000 results showing, this would make it a 2000 items post. What I'm trying to achieve is that if I'm showing 1000 results and only 5 are selected, I want to post only those 5 (and bind them correctly).

Comment: @Dely You could filter `modelBind` by whether `IsSelected` is true.

Comment: How can I do that? Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Dely try `var selected = modelBind.Results.Where(r => r.IsSelected).ToList();`

Comment: Okay, but that is filtering results that were already bound. If I check in Headers->Form Data in dev tools in browser, I still post all of the results (which are many). My goal is to post only those results that are selected, not filter them after they were posted.

Comment: @Dely If you want to filter at client side, you need to invoke ajax to query the non-disabled attributes and send request with them by form data.